# How can I read a very long list of command line arguments

Tags: c#, command-line

I use cygwin globbing to give me a long list of files. I want to process that list with c#.

There seems to be a restriction as to the number of arguments I can supply.

I know a work-around is to read from a file, HOWEVER, is there any way to read the command line args as stdin?

Comment: Why not just comma seperate the file names and read them as a single argument?

Comment: Unix globbing does not return in that format.

Comment: In that case, you could pipe the input in to read it as stdin.